# Functors and free objects in Hask

Tags: haskell, category-theory

Based on [Wikipedia's definition of a free object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object#Definition), it seems to me that every Functor is Free in Hask.  Conversely, every free object should also be a Functor.  Is this correct, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: A Haskell `Functor`, by itself, is not an object in Hask, it's an endofunctor on Hask.  Are you speaking about a free object in a different category than Hask?

Comment: Every functor in Hask is adjoint to what forgetful functor?

Comment: @luqui I think I'm talking about Hask, but I could be wrong.  What I mean is that if `F` a Functor, then `F a` should be some free object (we don't know what type) on the "set" `a`.

Comment: @n.m.  If `F` is a Functor, `F a` is the free object on `a`, then the forgetful functor would take `F a -> a`?

Comment: No, this is all totally wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean.  Often times categorical definitions are written in greater generality than one wants in a functional programing contexts.  Rather than using the wikipedia definition using concrete categories, consider the definition you get where you treat the kind of thing you want free as a parameter.

**Definition: free *foo*.**  A free *foo* on type `T` is an object `FT` such that `F` is a *foo*, and a function `i :: T -> FT` such that any other *foo* `S` and a function `f :: T -> S` there exists a unique *foo morphism* `f'` such that `f' . i = f`.

Insert say "monoid" and you get free monoids, groups and you get free groups, etc.  Note, this definition uses essentially no category theory and most certainly does not talk about functors.  It is less formal than the definition given by wikipedia, but should work intuitively. Given this definition, a **free construction** is a general way of making free objects.  For example `[]` provides a free construction for monoids, in that `[a]` is the free monoid on `a` for all `a`.

I don't think it is the case that all functors are free functors.  I also don't think it is the case that all free constructions in Hask are *Haskell* functors (that all free constructions lead to abstract functors is trivial).

My definition of "free" applied only to things of kind `*`, but a more general definition would also apply to other kinds.  For example, free monads.

You could go all out and do crazy things.  For example, you could probably define the free boolean algebra on `Sing k` (the singleton types of kind `k`) where `k` is enumerable using GADTs.  That this involves something "functorial" will be highly non-obvious in Hask.

Comment: What I was thinking is that what you call function `f` looks a lot like the first argument to `fmap`.  The function `i` also looks a lot like the function `pure`, so maybe what I'm thinking about actually applies to applicatives.  Also, based on your type signatures for `f` and `i`, I don't see how any type for `f'` could make the equation `f' . i = f` work.  Did you mean to say: `f . i = f'` and have the type of `f' :: FT -> FS`?

Comment: `f' :: FT -> S`, so `f' . i :: T -> S` which is what you want.  The naming may not have been the best.  Consider the case where `foo` is replaced with `Monoid`.  Then, my claim is that for any `a` and function `f :: a -> m` where `m` is a monoid, `f = mconcat . map f . (:[])`, and `mconcat . map f` is a monoid morphism.  I think you are correct that free constructions should tend to be pointed functors.

Comment: Not only a pointed functor, but a monad! `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, or in the above syntax `FT -> (T -> FU) -> FU`. Now, choose `S` to be `FU`, then we get for every `f :: T -> FU` a function `f' :: FT -> FU`, which is the same as `flip (>>=)`. (The adjunction between the free functor and the forgetful functor gives rise to this monad.) I have this packaged up here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free-functors/0.1.1/doc/html/Data-Functor-Free.html